# Loss function calculated outside tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I'm working on a GAN model. A generator creates an SVG, I built a discriminator that converts the SVGs into images and compares generated images with a reference dataset.

The output of may generator

```
generated_images_svg = generator(noise, training=True)
```

is a tensor of shape  (10, 10, 43) then the first dimension is the batch size.
I found a way to calculate the loss function manually, not inside tensorsflow, my loss function is inside its GradientTape

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as disc_tape:
    gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
```

Since the calculation is done outside tensorflow when I ask tensorflow to calculate parameters gradient

```
gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
```

It returns an array of null and therefore the parameters update fails

```
generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
```

Is there a standard way out in terms of tensorflow?

Comment: What do you mean by `calculation is done outside tensorflow`? Is it not done with tensorflow operators?

Comment: For my GAN I created a manual traing_step. In this procedure I calculated manually the loss function for the generator. As con consequence the calculation is not differentiable by tensorflow and I cannot do back propagation.

Comment: What kind of loss function do you use? Can't you wrap it into tensorflow operations?